# Does OpenSea support ERC2981 royalties?

Tags: ethereum, opensea

I cannot get answers from the OpenSea team about setting royalties in my smart contract itself using standards defined in EIP2981. But OpenSea does not show the royalty in test-net. Can someone please let me know?

Comment: Same here... also I found that some projects have Royalities with out implementing 2391 like this:

https://etherscan.io/address/0xbce3781ae7ca1a5e050bd9c4c77369867ebc307e#code

So.. must probable is not

Comment: don't think it does. we just use contractURI() function

Answer (score 0):

Opensea doesn´t support EIP-2981 at the time of writing. I think they will eventually, not sure how long it can take tho.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).